# merging two sorted lists, lower bound

Tags: algorithm, lower-bound

Using a decision tree and your answer to part (a), show that any algorithm that correctly merges two sorted lists must perform at least 2n − o(n) comparisons.

answer from part (a): 2n over n ways to divide 2n numbers into two sorted lists, each with n numbers
(2n over n) <= 2^h

h >= lg(2n)! / (n!)^2

= lg(2n!) - 2lg(n!)

**= Θ(2n*lg(2n)) - 2Θ(n*lg(n))** <----

**= Θ(2n)** <----

I don't understand the last step. How can it be Θ(2n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent logarithm of product as sum of separate logarithms ([the first property here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations)):

```
2*n*lg(2*n) = 2*n*(lg(2) + lg(n)) = 2*n*(1 + lg(n))
```

So

```
2*n*(1 + lg(n)) - 2*n*lg(n) = 
2*n+ 2*n*lg(n)) - 2*n*lg(n) = 2*n
```

Comment: Thanks for the help